# Multi-rate Multi-sensors reading for Ardruino

Tags: arduino

I just bought a new Arduino to play with few sensors to fetch their data. I got this code from here:

```
typedef void (*command)();

template <unsigned long wait_ms, command c>

void repeat() {
    static unsigned long start = millis();
    if (millis()-start >= wait_ms) {
        start += wait_ms;
        c();
    }
}

void task1()                   
{

}

void task2() 
{

}

void task3() 
{

}

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(4800);

}

void loop(){
  int aba=1000;
  repeat<1000, task2>();
  repeat<5000, task1>();  
  repeat<3000, task3>();    
}
```

The code above runs perfectly without any problem. However when I make change like this

```
void loop(){
      int aba=1000;
      repeat<aba, task2>();
      repeat<5000, task1>();  
      repeat<3000, task3>();    
    }
```

It got problem execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local variable `aba` is not a compile time constant.

If what you're after is a variable value for `wait_ms` (change at runtime), then you're out of luck. You'll need to implement a non-template version which can use run-time values.

Using a compile time constant with a template will usually be more efficient, however you duplicate code with each instance using different template parameter values.

For a variable wait you could do something like this:

```
typedef void (*command)();

void repeat(unsigned long wait_ms, command c, unsigned long &start);
void repeat(unsigned long wait_ms, command c, unsigned long &start) {
    if (millis()-start >= wait_ms) {
        start += wait_ms;
        c();
    }
}

static unsigned long task1Start, task2Start, task3Start;  

void task1() {Serial.println("task 1");}                 
void task2() {Serial.println("task 2");}   
void task3() {Serial.println("task 3");}   

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  task1Start = task2Start = task3Start = millis();
}

void loop(){
  int aba=1000;
  repeat( aba, task1, task1Start );
  repeat( random(5000, 10000), task2, task2Start );  
  repeat( random(50, 500), task3, task3Start );    
}
```

EDIT: As the function is no longer a template, the function only produces a single static `start` shared between each call. The template basically duplicated code for each set of inputs giving a unique `start` for each task.

This can be solved by adding in a third parameter that passes in a reference to the `start` variable for each specific task.

If you are going to be using many tasks, a `Task` object to encapsulate each task might be useful/easier to deal with.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for solving the int part :) However after i tried it only task 1 could run, task 2 and 3 were not ignored during execution.

Comment: It is because the `start` variable is now shared, solution and edit above :)

Comment: Great!! Thanks man! couldnt be more thankful :) 
After this i ll try to add an input listener to fetch data from PC for my project.